# How can I insert a special character as bullet point in powerpoint, when it is not part of the menu?

Tags: vba, windows, powerpoint, powerpoint-2010

I'd like to make the special character with the character code 25B0, which is 9648 in Unicode, become my bullet Point in PowerPoint. But it seems to be not part of the special characters menu in PowerPoint - I couldn't find it on Arial, Webdings, Wingdings 1-3 ... Is there any way to find/get it in there? Importing it as a picture is no useful alternative in my special case. Thank you for any ideas. (I work with PowerPoint 2010.)

The above would be my favourite solution. If not possible this way, I could think of a solution via VBA. Is there a possibilty to let the body text placeholder know, I want to use the special character 9648 on the second bullet level and the character 9649 on the third level?

This ist the code, I mentioned in my first answer to Steve:

```
Sub Bullets()
Dim Shp As Shape
Dim sld As Slide
Dim i As Integer
Set sld = Application.ActiveWindow.View.Slide
Set Shp = sld.Shapes.AddShape(Type:=msoShapeRectangle, Left:=416.97612, Top:=160.44084, Width:=323.9998, Height:=283.46439)
With Shp
.Fill.Visible = msoFalse
.Line.Visible = msoFalse
With .TextFrame
.TextRange.Text = "Text 1" & vbCrLf & "Text 2" & vbCrLf & "Text 3"
.VerticalAnchor = msoAnchorTop
.MarginBottom = "10"
.MarginLeft = "10"
.MarginRight = "10"
.MarginTop = "10"
.WordWrap = msoTrue
With .TextRange
.Font.Size = 14
.Font.Name = "Arial"
.Font.Color.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = ppAlignLeft
.ParagraphFormat.Bullet.UseTextColor = msoFalse
.ParagraphFormat.Bullet.UseTextFont = msoFalse
.ParagraphFormat.Bullet.Font.Color.RGB = RGB(9, 91, 164)
.Characters(1, 6).Font.Bold = msoTrue
            For i = 2 To 3
With .Paragraphs(i).ParagraphFormat.Bullet
.Visible = msoTrue
End With
            Next
With .Paragraphs(2)
.IndentLevel = 2
.ParagraphFormat.Bullet.Character = 9648
.ParagraphFormat.Bullet.RelativeSize = 1
End With
With .Paragraphs(3)
.IndentLevel = 3
.ParagraphFormat.Bullet.Character = 9649
.ParagraphFormat.Bullet.RelativeSize = 1
End With
End With
With .Ruler
 .Levels(2).FirstMargin = 14.173219
 .Levels(2).LeftMargin = 28.346439
 .Levels(3).FirstMargin = 28.346439
 .Levels(3).LeftMargin = 42.519658
End With
End With
.Select (msoFalse)
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Not a programming question - try [su] ?

Comment: Well, not in the first instance. But if there is no standard solution, maybe it is posible to do it with VBA. I could delete the standard placeholder and add a new one with the bullet parameters I need. I hoped, there is a less complicated way.

Comment: OK, well if it really is a programming question then you should probably [edit] the question and tags to make this clear, otherwise it will probably get migrated to [su], as it currently appears to be just a basic user-level question about PowerPoint.

Comment: Well, if it would be basic, I could solve it. ;-) I would prefer a solution without programming, but as far as I can see, it seems to be impossible.

Comment: If there's no character encoded at 25B0 in a given font, you can't use 25B0.  You'll need to find a font that includes it or choose a different bullet character.  VBA won't help; it can't pull characters that aren't there out of the air (or a font).

Comment: Thank you, Steve, this is in a way good News, because I have proof, that they are there. I just don't know where. I already tried to create them with VBA and it worked. Codes follows. It is just that I'm not able to get control on the bullets in the master Body text, as I'm not good in coding. And still, it might be easier to include them the usual way if only I knew where they hide ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not all fonts have all glyphs in the entire Unicode space occupied. There is a VBA solution but you should be able to do it with the UI by opening the Insert / Symbol dialog picking a decently populated Unicode don't e.g. Arial Unicode and typing the glyph's code into the character field.

In VBA you can set the bullet character with something like this:

```
 TextRange.Paragraphs(1).ParagraphFormat.Bullet.Character
```

But you need to set the relevant font too.

If using the UI, you set the font in the top left drop down (Arial Unicode MS in the example shown) and then type the glyph's code in Hex in the Character code field in the bottom right (25D5 in the screen shot).

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Jamie, yes, I know. That's not my problem. I added my code how to create the bullets in a normal shape. The problem is, how to do it in the body text placeholder on the master

Comment: Or, as an alternative, find out, where the character hides. In my code it works with Arial. But in the Insert Symbol Dialog I can't find it. That's finally the real core of the problem.

Comment: I added a screen shot above. Does it help?

Comment: Yes, I found it. Thank you, Jamie. Finally, I got both answers - yours, whre to find it, and Steve's, how to help myself with VBA. :-)

Answer (score 1):

To set the bullet character for the first paragraph in the slide master:

```
With ActivePresentation.Designs(1).SlideMaster.Shapes("Text Placeholder 2")
    With .TextFrame2.TextRange.Paragraphs(1)
        .ParagraphFormat.Bullet.Font.Name = "Arial"
        .ParagraphFormat.Bullet.Character = 1234
    End With
End With
```

If there are multiple masters (masters, not layouts), you'd choose the master you want by changing the .Designs(1) as needed.

You can set the bullet on different paragraphs by changing the .Paragraphs(x) value.

Comment: I'm sorry I cannot not mark both answers (Steve's and Jamie's) as "most helpful". In fact they were!

Comment: No worries; glad it helped.